# Having trouble reading items from a file (C++)

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

So, I'm having trouble getting the last item in a text file to read in to a string object.

I've created a class called "Car," and I'm supposed to have all of the parameters for a "Car" object read in from a file, but it won't register the last one.

The ifstream object is "data"

The variables are:

```
string carType;
string reportingMark;
int carNumber;
string kind;
bool loaded;
string destination;
```

The line in the text file reads as:

> Car       CN    819481   maintenance   false    NONE

This is what I have right now:

```
getline(data, ignore); // ignores the header line
data >> carType >> reportingMark >> carNumber >> kind >> loaded;
while (data.peek() == ' ') // this and the next lines were the suggestions of the teacher to bypass the spaces (of which there are more than it will display here)
   data.get();
getline(data, destination);
```

So, it will read everything in except for the "destination" part.

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more context, both in your code and example file.

Comment: how about giving a while loop to your "ifstream" object

Comment: Tell more about the `destination` variable. What does it output in the end? Is it missing letters? Is it empty? Raises errors? Strange symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

`data >> carType >> reportingMark >> carNumber >> kind >> loaded;`

Here you try to reed a Boolean variable `loaded` from a stream. You wish that reading `false` would work, but it doesn't. It accepts `0` or `1` only.

Instead, failing to read the Boolean variable will toggle the `err` bit of the stream, which makes reading everything else after that fail.

To check that, if you do `data.peek()` right after that line you will receive a `-1`, indicating no valid input.

To fix that you will need to either change you way of storing information to store `0/1` instead of `true/false`, or better yet:

Do: `data << boolalpha` before reading the data. This will make the stream interpret `true/false` as `0/1`.

Comment: Oh snap I didn't even notice that with the boolean variable!

Comment: I can't believe it, this is what was holding it up the whole time!  Thanks guy!

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be correct; except that I don't see the need to put the

> while (data.peek() == ' ')
>   data.get();
>
> getline(data, destination);

part to read the destination. Instead, you may simply read it as data >> destination.
Moreover, make sure your input file is opening correctly, by putting a check

> if(data.isOpen()){//cout something}

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: If `destination` can be more than one word (separated by spaces) then this won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to check the return value of all IO operations. If you add the error checks, you might be able to locate the problem and find a solution for it.

```
if (!getline(data, ignore)) // ignores the header line
{
   std::cerr << "Unable to read the header\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ( !(data >> carType >> reportingMark >> carNumber >> kind >> loaded))
{
   std::cerr << "Unable to read the data\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (data.peek() == ' ') // this and the next lines were the suggestions of the teacher to bypass the spaces (of which there are more than it will display here)
   data.get();

if ( !getline(data, destination) )
{
   std::cerr << "Unable to read the rest of the line\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about giving a while loop to your "ifstream" object, like this

```
    ifstream ifstreamObject;
        ifstreamObject.open("car.txt");


cout << "carType"<< ' '<< "reportingMark" << ' '<< "carNumber" <<' '<< "kind" <<' '<< "loaded"<<' '<<"destination"<< endl;
           while(ifstreamObject >> carType >> reportingMark >> carNumber >> kind >> loaded >> destination )
           {       cout <<"---------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                   cout << carType<< ' '<< reportingMark << ' '<< carNumber <<' '<< kind <<' '<< loaded<<' '<<destination<< endl;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try to read from the file with strtok function.

If you want, you can read this for more information [strtok function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

I have done this task recently, and I used strtok because it allow split each line of the file into a list of words. Also, it allow you to avoid assigning the punctuation symbols like spaces, etc. (So I found it very useful)

My example: I want to read some character data from a file, such as its race, its profession, its hitpoints, its attack and defense.

Each line of my file seems like this: Human/soldier/15/7/7

So, I define a char pointer that store the return value of strtok function and a char pointer that store the read word until finding a delimiter that you have considered previously. (In this example: The '/')

```
char* position = strtok(file, '/');
char* character_info = new char[size];
```

so, you store the line in character_info and you check the position value on each iteration until you finish reading the file.

```
while(position != NULL){
  // store position value
  // call again strtok
}
```

I hope that it will be helpful! =)

Cheers